# Why does appengine cpu usage not add to 100%?

Tags: google-app-engine, cpu-usage

I'm hosting an appengine app and have found that the biggest part of my costs is my CPU usage so I'm trying to reduce that. I'm trying to find where I can make the biggest gains from optimization, however, the dashboard on my app lists a bunch of URL's and their associated CPU usage. How come this doesn't add to 100%?

[image]

Comment: Just looked at the URL's associated with these numbers and not all my URL's are listed, why is this? How do I see all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That part of the admin console only shows a summary of the URLs that have received the most requests, and their corresponding CPU consumption, over the past 24 hours. It's not intended to represent a complete picture of all your app's URLs - which could be numerous.

Comment: is it then safe to assume that the URL's listed are the best candidates for CPU optimization (otherwise they wouldn't be on the list)?

Comment: If your app traffic is consistent, yes... If millions of people are hitting one very inefficient page once every three days, you won't see it here two days out of three.